# sentence classification in to predefined topics

Tags: nlp, text-classification, unsupervised-learning

What unsupervised machine learning algorithms can be used to categorize sentences in to a fixed number of topics based on certain words in them? Like election and president words falls under politics category. I have already tried guided lda to implement this, any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you found a suitable solution for your problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Word2vec model to create vectors of sentences and then implement clustering algorithm like k means clustering with number of topics as a parameter on these vectors.

Comment: But I want to give predefined categories like sports, politics like wise. I don't think kmeans will be able to do that.

Comment: Use KNN in that case.It would solve your probelem but it is time consuming.

Comment: KNN needs to be trained right? I don't have the data to train that model that's why I am looking for an unsupervised algorithm.

Comment: If you have some keywords under each category, then use them as labelled data. Suppose, a word such as bat. As this word is more close to cricket and game (2 nearest neighbours). This would fall under sports as your keywords cricket and game are keywords of sports.

Comment: @YoshithaPenaganti Can you recommend a solution that does not involve labels? (a 100% unsupervised solution)